# Alpine JS - VM11705:16 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'title') Error Issue

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

I made a widget using alpine js however, getting an error like and finding solution to my research. What do you think is the error in my code? When I pull the data, the header part is said to be incorrect. But I can't see a problem. Or I couldn't figure it out.

[Errors i see in console][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofmW1.png

```
<div class="text-base w-56 px-5 rounded-full overflow-hidden" x-data="{
                   textArray: [],
                text: '',
                textIndex: 0,
                charIndex: 0,
                pauseEnd: 2750,
                cursorSpeed: 420,
                pauseStart: 20,
                typeSpeed: 50,
                direction: 'forward'
             }" x-init="(() => {

                fetch('/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/219/?_fields=acf.positions&acf_format=standard')
                  .then(response => response.json())
                  .then(data => textArray = data.acf.positions  );



                let typingInterval = setInterval(startTyping, $data.typeSpeed);



             function startTyping(){
                let current = $data.textArray[$data.textIndex].title;
                if($data.charIndex > current.length){
                     $data.direction = 'backward';
                     clearInterval(typingInterval);
                     setTimeout(function(){
                        typingInterval = setInterval(startTyping, $data.typeSpeed);
                     }, $data.pauseEnd);
                }

                $data.text = current.substring(0, $data.charIndex);
                if($data.direction == 'forward'){
                    $data.charIndex += 1;
                 } else {
                    if($data.charIndex == 0){
                        $data.direction = 'forward';
                        clearInterval(typingInterval);
                        setTimeout(function(){

                            $data.textIndex += 1;
                            if($data.textIndex >= $data.textArray.length){
                                $data.textIndex = 0;
                            }

                            typingInterval = setInterval(startTyping, $data.typeSpeed);
                        }, $data.pauseStart);
                    }
                    $data.charIndex -= 1;
                 }

             }

             setInterval(function(){
                if($refs.cursor.classList.contains('hidden')){
                    $refs.cursor.classList.remove('hidden');
                } else {
                    $refs.cursor.classList.add('hidden');
                }
             }, $data.cursorSpeed);
         })()">


            <span x-text="text"></span>
            <span class="opacity-70" x-ref="cursor">|</span>
        </div>
```

Thanks in advance for your suggestions and help.

Answer (score 1):

It's complaining that `$data.textArray[$data.textIndex]` is undefined, and you're trying to read `.title` from it.

when you first load your widget you do a fetch to populate `textArray`, but until that returns your `textArray` is empty so when you're trying to call `let current = $data.textArray[$data.textIndex].title` it's returning the error

You basically need to ensure textArray has data before you try to access it:

- you could move everything into your `.then(data => textArray = data.acf.positions  );` so it's only started when the fetch has been called.
- or you could put a simple `if (textArray.length === 0) return;` line at the start of your `startTyping` function so it doesn't try to do anything until textArray is populated

might not be your only issue, but this is the cause of the error you've posted